# Django date comparison throws exception

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm generating a date in this way,

```
profile.key_expires = datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=2)

if profile.key_expires > datetime.now()
```

This throws an exception, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What exception? Please paste the complete traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Django sets `USE_TZ = True` in `settings.py`, meaning that all date and time manipulations have to be done by taking into account timezones. In that case, using naive datetime objects from the standard library is likely to throw an error. As you didn't provide any information about the error you got, it's hard to claim that your error is related to timezone.

However, assuming it is, you can either disable timezone awarness in Django by setting `USE_TZ = False` in your `settings.py`, or by using Django built-in timezone support as explained and illustrated here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/